# How to create bots in several languages ​(FR, AR, EN ..)?

Tags: websphere, watson-assistant

How to create bots in several languages ​​(FR, AR, EN ..)?
Is the solution to group several languages ​​at the level of a single Bots or create a bot per language?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

i often thought of this, though with companies linked to ours.

Since they use other names and products (words in your casee) then others i tend to create one workspace per company and in your case per language.

Furthermore it could mess up the model in my opinion.

Hope that helps!